# how to open mysql.sock

Tags: mysql, mysql.sock

I can use mysql client to open mysql.sock with system root user. but I can't use other system user use thee mysql client. the error message is:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/mnt/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)
```

before this, I only use setfacl command on mysql directory:

```
setfacl -m u:hank:rx mysql
setfacl -m d:u:hank:rx mysql
```

then i can't access mysql with mysql client tool.
how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's because your login user has no available permission to access your [MySQL] process.